# Dont want to redirect after registration, possible?

Tags: users, redirection

I have a lightbox pop up when a link is clicked to sign up for the site but, after signing up i don't want them to redirect to their user profile page, I need them to stay on the same exact page. Is this possible?

I tried login destination but that feature only works for the login not registration.

Comment: What module shows the Lightbox pop-up with the login link?

Comment: im using hardcoded modal plugin called leanModal. its just a lightweight modal that will show the register form in it

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules).

Comment: I have that installed and couldn't seem to get it to make the user stay on the same page after actually making a new account, you have an idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module.  It has alot more features and community support than login destination module

Comment: I have it installed but doesn't do what I need it to do.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this Drdupal 6 or 7?

Comment: This is drupal 6

Answer (score 1):

Cleanest way is probably to just write a little module. In it, use hook_user() to change the destination URL after login:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user().
 */
function mymodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'register':
      // set the redirect url to <front>
      $_REQUEST['destination'] = '<front>';
      // OR, uncomment the following to disable redirecting completely:
      // unset($_REQUEST['destination']);
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this in your own custom module in Drupal 7:

```
function mymodulename_form_user_register_form_alter(){
    $_REQUEST['destination'] = 'anywhere_you_want_to_go_to';
}
```

`hook_form_user_register_form_alter()` always runs on the registration form. Change **mymodulename** to your module and make sure it's on.

The second line is the line that redirects on submit (if it validates). I don't know of any way to not redirect, but you can redirect to the page you're redirecting away from for the same result. Change the **"anywhere_you_want_to_go_to"** string to the page you want to go to. eg. *"user/register"* or *"<front>"*.

Comment: The OP is asking for a way to avoid the users are redirected to another page once they submitted the registration form.